# gmaps4rails v2 fitMapToBounds()

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails, gmaps4rails2

If I click something to add 5 markers to the map that are spread out over, say, 100 miles - the markers are added, and the map zooms out to fit them all.

If I then click something that shows markers that are spread out over, say, 2 miles... the markers disappear properly, but the map is not zooming back in.

I'm using 2.1.1

This is my javascript call:

```
Gmaps.store.handler.removeMarkers(Gmaps.store.markers);
Gmaps.store.markers = Gmaps.store.handler.addMarkers(<%= raw @hash.to_json %>, {
  draggable: false,
  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
});
Gmaps.store.handler.bounds.extendWith(Gmaps.store.markers);
Gmaps.store.handler.fitMapToBounds();
```

Am I missing a call?  I thought `removeMarkers` cleared the clusterer now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must explicitly reset your bounds:

```
handler.resetBounds();
```

Comment: Have I told you I love you before? Where's the best place to call that? I tried it in a few places, and I'm getting a flash of the markers.  As in, the markers drop, then they flash once, then all is well.  Same thing, above or below the `removeMarkers()` call.

Comment: A flash of markers? But bounds are not linked to map or markers... Weird

Comment: If the bounds don't change, there is no marker flash. When the bounds are different, there is a noticeable flash. It's not a big deal, just mentioning its presence.

Comment: Life-saver your answer, @apneadiving ! Thanks again!